# Android layout - position layouts

Tags: android

I have a RelativeLayout with three child layouts. Customer info in the top layout (align parent top), three buttons in the center layout and a banner in the bottom layout (align parent bottom).

I am filling from the bottom up in order to get the bottom banner to align to the bottom properly.

The issue is getting the center layout to display properly. My top layout is forcing the center layout down and if I disable 1 or 2 of the center buttons (gone) I need them to float gravitate to the top of the layout. I can get variations of what I need to display properly but not everything placed right.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/adLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/ad_contact_background"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAd"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+android:id/ad_contactAdImageView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutContact"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutAd" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ad_contactWebsiteButton"
            android:background="@drawable/button_black"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ad_contactEmailButton"
            android:background="@drawable/button_black"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ad_contactPhoneButton"
            android:background="@drawable/button_black"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
            android:typeface="sans" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayoutContact"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ad_contactTitleTextView"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ad_contactAddressTextView"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:typeface="sans" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post an image of your desired layout. Just for and Idea, how you want your layout.

Comment: Got it. I just needed to render the center layout last. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I just needed to render the center layout last.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the below modified xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/adLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTitle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ad_contactTitleTextView"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="24dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ad_contactAddressTextView"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:typeface="sans" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutContact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutTitle"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ad_contactWebsiteButton"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ad_contactEmailButton"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ad_contactPhoneButton"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
            android:typeface="sans" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+android:id/ad_contactAdImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```